# Replace multiple lines by one line starting from the next line of the occurrence

Tags: awk, sed

I want to replace multiple lines starting from the next line of the occurrence by one line.

For example, I have the following section of an html file:

```
...
<div class="myclass">
  <p textselect="true">
     one
     two
     three
  </p>
</div>
...
```

I want to end up with

```
...
<div class="myclass">
  <p textselect="true">
     hello
  </p>
</div>
...
```

...but I need to be able to match the string with `<p textselect="true">`, rather then with `one`, as I don't know what that string (`one`) is going to be.

Right now my solution is pretty nasty. I am appending a placeholder after `<div class="myclass">`, I delete the placeholder and the next 3 lines, then I append again the string I want. All with sed. I need it to be either with `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Obligatory [use an HTML/XML parser to parse HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552) link. Why do you _need_ awk or sed to do this job? For example, if your HTML is well-formed XML, then `xmlstarlet ed -O -u '//div[@class="myclass"]/p[@textselect="true"]' -v 'hello' file.html` would do it

Comment: @glennjackman because it goes in a `Dockerfile`, with an alpine base image, where I do have sed and awk, but I dont have python, perl or xmlstarlet. And I am trying to keep the image as light as possible without having to add extra layers deleting packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/<p textselect="true">/{:a;N;/<\/p>/!ba;s/(\n\s*).*\n/\1hello\n/}' file
```

Gather up lines between `<p textselect="true">` and `</p>` and replace the string inbetween with `hello`.

Alternative:

```
sed -n '/<p textselect="true">/{p;n;s/\S\+/hello/;h;:a;n;/<\/p>/!ba;H;g};p' file
```

N.B. Both solutions expect at least one line to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/<\/p>/{f=0} !f; sub(/<p textselect="true">/,"  hello"){print; f=1}' file
...
<div class="myclass">
  <p textselect="true">
    hello
  </p>
</div>
...
```

or if your replacement string `hello` might contain `&` (a backreference metacharacter for `*sub()`) then:

```
$ awk '/<\/p>/{f=0} !f; sub(/<p textselect="true">/,"  "){print $0 "hello"; f=1}' file
...
<div class="myclass">
  <p textselect="true">
    hello
  </p>
</div>
...
```